# fetching a Key from a class into an another class

Tags: java

Lets say I have a class in which i generate a DB with some keys, now I want to have an other class in which i use for example the "key123" as I named it in the following, how can I do that? Is that possible to just copy&paste the @Basic and public String key123 in that other class? Will that Basic annotation fetch it from the DB into that class? even when they both have different packages?

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic
@XmlAttribute
@XmlID
private Long id;

@Basic
private String someotherKey;

@Basic
public String key123;
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to read and understand about Database Normalisation and Relational Databases.

Comment: @TheresaForster probably yes, right now I can't invest much time since I have to deliver it now, would be helpful if you have an idea about my problem Madam :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use the MVC model of development

Class Keys   - the DB Table as an object using the @Entity annotation etc

Class KeysDao - The Data Access Object that does all the DB calls keysDao.update(Keys), keysDao.add(Keys), keysDao.get(id) keysDao.getAllKeys()  etc.

Class KeyService - this has the Business Logic so you can say in any other class keyService.getKey(id) and get the Key from the DB returned. Then you can get it in any other class you wish.

If you mean get in another table you need to look at SQL table joins and create your query correctly (or create a view in the DB - not a lot of people know but you can update and add using a View meaning you can make one commit with the data as you use in the view and not have to even know the real  normalised DB beneath.